# For any linear operator A acting in Space Kn will A.0 be always equal to 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

This question comes from the assertion that a trivial subspace consisting only of element zero {0}, will be an invariant subspace for all A.

This means:
A.0 = 0 for any A so that the invariance holds true.

Does this have to necessarily hold true for any operator A to be linear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! This will always be true for a linear operator $A$. To see this:

$A(0) = A(0+0) = A(0)+A(0) = 2A(0)$, and the only way this can happen is if $A(0)=0$.

Comment: Thanks. So that means any A that takes x from x-> x+x0 is not linear?

Comment: I don't really understand your question I'm afraid! Can you try and rephrase it for me?

Comment: No worries, @AlgTop I was imagining if a hypothetical operator A that simply adds a constant vector x0 to any vector x in a space Kn is also linear. I cannot imagine yet a matrix A that accomplishes this transformation, but still my question remains.

Comment: The thinking there is, if such an operator exists then A.o will be taken to a non zero vector Vn contravening the said assertion that A.o = o for all A

Comment: Well put it into the linearity criteria and see what happens. Say $T(x) = x+x_0$. Then $T(x +\lambda y) = (x +\lambda y) + x_0 = (x +\lambda y) + x_0$. It should be clear that this is never going to equal $T(x) + \lambda T(y)$ unless $x_0 = 0$.

Comment: @Ace: Correct. Such an $A$ (as in your comment above) would be an *affine* operator, not a linear one.

Comment: @AlgTop and zipirovich. Thanks a bunch guys, clarifies it a lot.